# GWT Visualisation Table get selected column via Java

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT Visualisation (Chart) Table, the issue I am facing is that SelectEvent returned by the OnSelectHandler does not return any information on cell or column.

I want to know, how can I find out the selected column index via Java not in JS.

```
table.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {

            JsArray<Selection> s = table.getSelections();
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); i++){


                  if (s.get(i).isCell()) {
                    b.append(" cell ");
                    b.append(s.get(i).getRow());
                    b.append(":");
                    b.append(s.get(i).getColumn());
                  } else if (s.get(i).isRow()) {
                    b.append(" row ");
                    b.append(s.get(i).getRow());
                  } else {
                    b.append(" column ");
                    b.append(s.get(i).getColumn());
                  }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by does not return information ? What does `getColumn()` and `getRow()` methods return ?

Comment: The size of the table.getSelections() is 1, and it contains the row index value. so it does not have cell or column information.

Comment: What if you call `isCell()` for the selection object, does it return false ?

Comment: the selection object that is returned by the table.getSelections() only contains the row elements, even when we select multiple rows on the table.

Comment: Yes I understand. For better understanding the situation I just need to know the attributes of this single element it returns, please. What are the values returned by `getSelections().get(0).getColumn()'` , `getSelections().get(0).getRow()`, `getSelections().get(0).isCell()`, `getSelections().get(0).isRow()` and `getSelections().get(0).isColumn()`